# python: detect imposter user names; match a whole string beside specific character substitutions

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a little detection script that and spot out "impostor" usernames/screen names in python2. For instance using "aIIison" (with 2 capital i's) to impersonate a user name "allison" (with lower case L's).
The conditions are, the length of the names have to be the same, all characters have to be the same EXCEPT the substituted letters zero's instead of capital O, or vice versa, capital i's instead of lower case L's etc.

Here is what i have so far, and now I'm just lost.
I know this is a mess. Any input on how i should properly structure the logic on this?

```
mylist = ['allison', 'allisPn']
name_to_eval = 'aIIison'

for names in mylist:
    flag = 0
    if len(names) == len(name_to_eval):
        for i in range(len(name_to_eval)):
            err1 = name_to_eval[i] == 'I' and names[i] == 'l'
            cond1 = not err1 and name_to_eval[i] == names[i]
            if  err1 and cond1:
                print names
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a list of potential substitutions:

```
subs = {
  'I': 'l', 
  '0': 'O', 
  # ...
}
```

Then compare the two strings where you applied all the substitutions:

```
def compare(s1, s2, subs):
  for a, b in subs.items():
    s1 = s1.replace(a, b)
    s2 = s2.replace(a, b)
  return s1 == s2
```

Using your code:

```
mylist = ['Allison']
name_to_eval = 'AIIison'

for name in mylist:
  if compare(name, name_to_eval, subs):
    print('Conflicting names: {} and {}'.format(name, name_to_eval))
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a dictionary mapping "real" to "fake" characters. The fake ones can also be a longer string, in case there are multiple possible substitutions. Then, just `zip` the `real` and `fake` username and check whether each character in the fake name `f` corresponds to the real character `r` or any of it's common substitutions.

```
>>> subst = {"l": "I|", "o": "0", "s": "5$", ...}

>>> real, fake = "allison", "aI|i$0n"

>>> all(f == r or f in subst.get(r, '') for r, f in zip(real, fake))
True
```

This assumes that both names have the same length and the "real" name only contains "proper" characters and no "leet speak" substitutions, although the letter could also be supported by extending the `subst` dict accordingly.